What is meant by Weyl's test for straightness of a line? Is this a problem of translation from the German original?
The text quoted below is taken from Hermann Weyl's Space-Time-Matter.  The part about a straight line being an axis of rotation makes sense.  That a line is determined by two points is not difficult to accept.  But "Any other line can, even when two of its points are kept fixed, be brought into another position by a congruent transformation" has me confused.  If I have a line running through my room, and I fix two of its points relative to the walls, it isn't going anywhere.  If I borrow two of its points and hold them fixed  then I can slide the line along itself such that those point remain on the line.  If I rotate the room using the line as the axis of rotation, then I get the result of the subsequent sentence. So why talk about "Any other line?"

First of all the straight line. Its distinguishing feature is that
it is determined by two of its points. Any other line can, even when
two of its points are kept fixed, be brought into another position
by a congruent transformation (the test of straightness). Thus, if
$A$ and $B$ are two different points, the straight line $g=AB$
includes every point which becomes transformed into itself by all
those congruent transformations which transform $AB$ into themselves.
(In familiar language, the straight line lies evenly between its points.)
Expressed kinematically, this is tantamount to saying that we regard
the straight line as an axis of rotation.

I've included the original German language text for reference. Can the English language translation be reworded (corrected?) in order to make sense?

Zunächst die gerade Linie! Ihre Eigentümlichkeit ist, daß sie durch
zwei ihrer Punkte bestimmt ist; jede andere Linie kann noch unter
Festhaltung zweier ihrer Punkte durch kongruente Abbildung in eine
andere Lage gebracht werden (Linealprobe). Also: sind $A,B$ zwei
verschiedene Punkte, so gehört zu der geraden Linie $g=AB$ jeder
Punkt, der bei allen kongruenten Abbildungen in sich übergeht, die
$A$ und $B$ in sich überführen (die gerade Linie »weicht nach keiner
Seite aus«). Kinematisch ausgedrückt, kommt das darauf hinaus, daß
wir die gerade Linie als Rotationsachse auffassen.


I don't read German, and am not really qualified to speak on that, but it looks to me like there is a distinction between a straight line and a line.  The latter might better be called a "curve"?

I agree that he is eliminating non-straight "lines".  The book is about Relativity, both Special and General, so not-so straight "lines" will come into play.  This discussion is about Euclidean Geometry.  He has to make it before he can break it.  But I could fix two points of a circle and rotate it about its center such that the fixed points remain on the circle.

(1) You cannot rotate a circle and keep the points fixed (except by rotating by a multiple of $2\pi$. The points will still be on the circle, but they will be in different places.  (2) Pay attention to the quantification.  There may be multiple transformations which fix the line, but the description is about sets which are fixed by all of the relevant transformations.

@XanderHenderson I mean to borrow two points of the circle and hold them fixed in space while the circle is rotated in its plane about its center.  Those point remain on the circle.  But that begs the question what does Weyl mean by "when two of its points are kept fixed"?  Fixed on the moving line, or fixed in space, or both?  I assume he means both.  So that would mean exactly one line can satisfy the condition at a time.

It means fixed in the space.  Imagine the set of all (congruent) transformations (I'm not super familiar with the terminology, but I would guess that this means orthogonal transformations, e.g. those which preserve length and angle) which act on a space and which fix two points.  The only curve through two points which is fixed by all of those transformations is the straight line (per the definition).

Note that in your example of the circle, if the two points are on opposite sides of a diameter of that circle, you can reflect the circle across that diameter.  The only two points of the circle which remain fixed by this transformation are the two selected points.  Every other point is swapped with it's reflection.  The relevant part of the translation is "...the straight line $g=AB$ includes every point which becomes transformed into itself."  The points are transformed to themselves (the points are fixed).

@XanderHenderson First he says a line is determined by two of its points.  Then he says any other line can be brought to a new position even if two of its points are held fixed.  The only new "position" is to have its points rotated in place, which is kind of meaningless to me.  But, let's assume that's what he means.  Then why say "any other line...", rather than saying every line?

Fix two points in the plane.  Consider any curve which passes through those two points, and the set of all possible congruent transformations.  For most of these curves, there will be some transformation which sends some point on the curve to a different point in space.  There is a unique curve which passes through those points which has the property that every single point on that curve is sent to itself by every possible transformation.  That special, unique curve is the straight line.

The translation is OK except for In familiar language, the straight line lies evenly between its points, which is too much of an interpretation. I would translate the original die gerade Linie »weicht nach keiner Seite aus« as follows: The straight line does not sidestep to either side.

I still don't understand: "Any other line can, even when two of its points are kept fixed, be brought into another position by a congruent transformation." A congruent transformation is such that if an observer is transformed with his environment he can't detect a change. How can two points of a line be held fixed while the line is moved to another position?

Sorry I only wanted to answer your translation request.

@StevenThomasHatton What do you mean by an "observer"?   From a mathematical perspective, I understand a congruent transformation to be one which preserves angle and distance.  You seem to understand it to mean something else...?

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/43006/43006-pdf.pdf See the beginning of Chapter 1 to understand why I used that unconventional summary definition.  Go as far as the discussion of rigid bodies.  Warning:the English translation is full of errors.

@MartinBrandenburg The translation leaves much to be desired.  For example   eine Schar paralleler Geraden is rendered a group of parallel lines.  Which might work if not for the fact that group has a specific and important different meaning in this context.  I have been editing the raw tex file as I read.  I replaced Schar->group with Schar->family.  I just found that Schar can translate to flock which is really beautiful, and might be what I end up using.  So we have flock of parallel lines.

"eine Schar" is a bit old-fashioned terminology for a family of things which are closely related; usually by a parameter. For example, $x \mapsto x^2 + t$ is a "Schar von Parabeln". It is still used in school (when I was at school, which is many years ago), not sure if anywhere else.
